# Слово "немигаючи"

Tags: словообразование

Есть ли такое слово? Если нет, можно ли использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "немигаючи" часто встречается в народно-поэтической речи

Встреча с Игорем (былина)

"Так случилось, что Игорь, князь киевский, той порой ждал-искал перевозчика. От древлян возвращался он в Киев град, без дружины, один одинешенек. Видит – лодка подходит рыбацкая, просит в Киев грести перевозчика. Поначалу он принял за юношу в том челне перевозчицу девицу. По пути перевозчик и спрашивает: как найти ему в Киеве Игоря? Удивился вопросу он юноши: “А зачем тебе нужен князь киевский?”Тут то Ольга ему и ответила, что князь Игорь, богами ей суженый. Едет с князем она играть свадебку, не одна она едет, а с приданным. Рассмеялся князь Игорь невесело, видит короб у девушки нищенский, в нем трава лишь речная на донышке, на траве лежит щука зубастая, злобно смотрит в глаза НЕМИГАЮЧИ".